# Why can't I see my LAN network with Gigabyte GA-H77-DS3H?

Tags: 12.10, networking, ethernet, lan

I can't connect via Ethernet cable to my Linksys WRTSL554GS router.  I think my mobo, a Gigabyte GA-H77-DS3H does not have Wi-Fi so I don't have that option either.

When I do a `ifconfig` this is what I see:

```
lo      Link encap:Local LoopBack
        tnet addr:127.0.01 Mask:255.0.0.0
        tnet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436  Metric:1
        RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overuns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overuns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)  TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

I do not see the `eth0` or `eth1` listed.

Do I have to do something in the BIOS?  I am not familiar with this BIOS on the new motherboard.

Comment: What does 'ifconfig -a' say?

Comment: the output of lspci and lshw might be useful here too

Comment: @user133079 You can upload the output of the commands in paste.ubuntu.com and link it in your question.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1675774/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1675789/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1675799/

Answer (score 1):

Your Atheros AR8161 uses the relatively new driver *alx*. It is provided by linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic; assuming you are running Ubuntu 12.10, known as Quantal. You could download it and all its dependencies here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic. Note that you need all its dependencies:

*linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-23-generic <--or matching your current running kernel version

..and its dependencies:

*dpkg

*linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic <--or matching your current running kernel version

..and all its dependencies as well.

You can download them on another computer and drag and drop them to your desktop. Install with:

```
cd Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

If there are any missing dependencies, get and install them, too. Be sure to get the versions appropriate for your archtecture; either 32- or 64-bit.

OR...you could do as I'd do. Borrow from a friend or another computer temporarily or even buy a cheap ethernet card and plug it in, get a connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic
```

Two minutes later, when it's done, your on-board ethernet should be working.

If you are not running 12.10, our strategy may be different.

Comment: My goal is to make a LiveCD.  Is it possible to do add the new driver it's dependencies to the 12.10 iso that I have?

Comment: Probably not to your existing iso. You probably need Remastersys: http://www.remastersys.com/